# Manage Alt+Tab in .net application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows

I am developing a simple chat application which works in LAN. I have a problem in ALt+Tab.
When I open 2 applications (One is mine and another one say Firefox), now it switches properly between two windows when I press Alt+Tab.

Now I will minimize firefox. So now my app is the only one in foreground. Now if I press Alt+Tab, firefox comes foreground which is not expected (or I dont expect).

How to make Alt+Tab not work when all windows are in minimized state ?

I am using vb.net but c# is also OK for me and for example I have given firefox; there may be n number of windows in minimized state.

Please help me.

Comment: Changing your expectations to align with default OS behavior would be much more productive and user-friendly approach.

Comment: No, you're not trying to make your application behave like the default OS behaviour.  What you describe as happening now IS the default OS behaviour so you don;t have to do anything.  If you are trying to do anything then you're trying to make your app behave differently to every other app.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing `ALT` + `TAB` in Windows (or other OS) is supposed to switch between every active application that is running and has a top-level Window. So the behavior you are describing is actually working the way it is supposed to.

More on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-Tab) about that.

However, it is possible to hack this behavior by capturing the `ALt-Tab` event. It is actually used by several remote control application so they can transmit commands from one computer to another.

[Here is a start up guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante), but beware that you get into Windows weird APIs and low-level functionnality. Use at your own risk...

Comment: I dont want to disable the Alt+Tab functionality permanently. I want it disable only when my app is in foreground and others in minimized state. How to know all the other applications are in minimized state ?

Comment: Another question is Why do you want that ? I'm sure you want to achieve somethin... You can ask the Windows API for all the active windows, then check all of them if they are minimized or not...